# Visual Studio C# project in Monodevelop - Errors for GenerateSatelliteAssemblies and GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to setup a C# project that is compatible with both Windows 10 / Visual Studio 2015 and Ubuntu 16.04 / MonoDevelop.
In the MonoDevelop project options, I set the target framework to `Mono / .NET 4.5` and configuration to `Debug|x86`.

The `.csproj` file now looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{myprojectsguid}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>myproject</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>myproject</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Externalconsole>true</Externalconsole>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Externalconsole>true</Externalconsole>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

When I build, I get this message:

```
Erzeuge Projektmappe: myproject (Debug|x86)

myproject (Debug|x86) wird erzeugt

Build started 26.05.2016 22:05:49.
__________________________________________________
Project "pathto/myproject.csproj" (Build target(s)):

    Target PrepareForBuild:
        Configuration: Debug Platform: x86

    Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
    No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.

    Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because its outputs are up-to-date.
Done building project "pathto/myproject.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
     0 Warning(s)
     0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.0785520

--------------------- Fertig ---------------------

Erzeugung erfolgreich.
```

The message seems to contradict itself. The English part says "build failed", while the localized/German part says "build successful". But no executable was created.
I did not find any applicable information about `GenerateSatelliteAssemblies` or `GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute`.
Do I need to change the project settings even further? Do I need to supply some missing files?

**Update:**
Apparently, some packages were missing. So I ran `sudo apt-get install mono-complete`. Now the project builds successfully.
Though, the notifications about `GenerateSatelliteAssemblies` and `GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute` are still there. Looks like they don't break the build. I still wonder what they mean.

Comment: what version of mono and monodevelop are you using?

Comment: Mono version 4.2.1 and MonoDevelop version 5.10. I installed both from the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm just posting the answer that the asker wrote in the question.)

For the asker, it turned out that some packages were missing. The asker ran `sudo apt-get install mono-complete`, and then the project would build successfully.

Comment: I also had the problem that the asker had, and this solution fixed the problem for me, too. I suspect that in my case, the problem was caused by upgrading Ubuntu from version 15.04 to version 16.10. The upgrade must have automatically deleted some necessary packages.